# How to fetch regex match search in twitter

Tags: python, tweepy

```
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    data = []

    search = "$telsa"

    for tweet in api.search(q=search, lang="en"):
        tweet = tweet._json
        for i in tweet:
            data.append({
                "username": tweet["user"]["name"],
                "text": tweet["text"],
                "created_at": tweet["created_at"],
                "place": tweet["place"]
            })

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Here i am trying fetch tweets where any words starts with $ inside the sentence.
So it will search tweets where sentence includes names like

$telsa, $wipro, $microsoft etc

I mean all tweets which includes $ in the word

Answer (score 0):

"$" has special meaning in regexes(buffer end) - you can try escaping or urlencoding the "$" character and seeing if you get better results.

Comment: I need the tweets which contains dollar symbol

Comment: Any way i can do this ?